# Как посчитать количество строк в массиве php?

Tags: php, массивы

```
count($massiv) <= выводит количество столбцов в массиве
```

Мне же нужно узнать количество строк в массиве.

Comment: Т.е. в массиве могут хранится не только строки и нам надо посчитать количество строк?

Comment: забрали мы из базы несколько строк..они в виде массива..
потом я из этого массива делаю таблицу


$queryss2 = "$qss2";
$resultss2 = mysql_query($queryss2);
print "<table bgcolor=FFFF99 BORDER=2><tr><th></th><th>№ Комплекта</th><th>Гарнитура</th><th>Наушник</th><th>Дополнительно</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) :
print "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='s[]' value='".$row['nk']."' ></td><td>".$row["nk"]."</td><td>".$row["blut"]."</td><td>".$row["yho"]."</td><td>".$row["dopoln"]."</td></tr>";
endwhile;

мне нужно понять сколько строк в этой таблице получится

Comment: @Kromster Да вы батенька некрокорректор =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, увлекаюсь иногда )

Answer (score 5):

В зависимости от того, что вы имеете в виду: либо `sizeof($massiv)`, либо `sizeof($massiv[0])`.

Comment: блин я может что то не так понимаю, но мне нужно следующее
есть массив
54 абв 374
83 гдз 367
27 вла 379 
мне нужно посчитать количество этих строк
то бишь в данной примере 3 строки..как сие сделать?

Comment: Ну так попробуйте оба варианта, какой вам подойдет. `sizeof($massiv)` показывает кол-во строк, `sizeof($massiv[0])` - кол-во столбцов.

Comment: не знаю почему, может быть ошибка у меня в запросе.. однако в таблице я вижу 5 строк, sizeof($massiv) мне говорит 10 =)